# Django - when overriding a model's save() function, should super() take any arguments?

Tags: django, django-models

Regarding the syntax for overriding a model's save() method, I've encountered a strange (to me, anyway) discrepancy between the Django official documentation, and numerous answers here on StackOverflow. I'm hoping someone can explain the difference I'm observing.

Here's the example from Django's current official documentation:
(source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

Note the call to super() -- it has *no* arguments.

Now, for contrast, here's the syntax I keep finding in every search I've done on this same subject: that is, overriding the save() method of a django Model. There are too many examples to link, so I'm simply going to rewrite the above example code, using the exact syntax I've found in at least 6 different posts on the subject:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # look at the arguments used here!
        do_something_else()
```

The obvious difference: super() takes 2 arguments: the name of the Model ('Blog') and self.

Is this simply a case of a recent(ish) Django update that made this syntax unnecessary? That seems the most likely explanation, but since it's not clear and I haven't confirmed this, I'm asking here. Or is there some other explanation of this difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Since Python-3.x, for simple `super`'s, you do not have to pass parameters anymore. This has nothing to do with Django itself, but with Python.

Comment: To add to @WillemVanOnsem , you should check out method-resolution order or multiple-resolution order. Here is a good article on it: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html